# How do I interact with Bitcoin Core from NodeJS?

Tags: bitcoind, json-rpc, node.js

I am new to the Bitcoin world. I have installed [Bitcoin Core](https://bitcoincore.org/en/download/) on a Windows machine and am running the full node. I want to develop a nodejs app that would be running on the same machine interacting with the Bitcoin node for 'balance/transfer funds/create wallet/etc'. I will really appreciate any pointers or sample code to achieve that.

Comment: Searching for "Bitcoin RPC protocol" might help you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend looking at Bcoin. It is a full node implementation used by Purse.io but also includes a rich API for interacting with the Node and wallets. All of it running in NodeJS. Documentation is sparse but getting better.

http://bcoin.io/

Otherwise, bitcoinjs https://github.com/bitcoinjs/bitcoinjs-lib is a Javascript library that lets you parse, create, and sign transactions. But it doesn't handle the hard part of querying the network, caching information about transactions and wallets, or picking inputs and calculating fees when you want to spend.

Comment: For bitcoinjs-lib, Can I can configure it to connect to my local running bitcoin core full node ?

Comment: BitcoinJs does not handle th networking for you. You’d have to do the calls to the Core node yourself and use bitcoinjs to parse the data. I know, not friendly. Hence why I recommend bcoin instead.

Comment: My company also builds a mobile wallet Edge. It is built as a JavaScript SDK for React Native and the web, but in theory it runs fine on NodeJS as that’s how we test it. It CAN connect to your node if you run ElectrumX on top of your node. It can fully handle the networking between wallet and node and can even connect to multiple nodes concurrently. Sending and receiving is abstracted out to just a couple JavaScript calls. It may be worth trying out. https://GitHub.com/EdgeApp/edge-core-js

Comment: Can you suggest me how I get started with bcoin. I want to run a full node and then write nodejs code to get balance/transfer funds. Any sample code will be really helpful.

Comment: Sorry. I can only recommend heading to bcoin.io and looking at the docs. They also have a Slack channel where you can ask questions.